# logrotate script for xinetd postrotate

Tags: logrotate, xinetd

I need help with rotating my xinetd.log file. I'm using CentOS8 and I have this logrotate file:

```
/var/log/xinetd.log {
    compress
    dateext
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    copytruncate
    postrotate
    /etc/init.d/xinetd reload
    endscript
}
```

But I get "postrotate error" or something, I lost the logs when running the debug. But I know the post rotate won't work.

My main problem is how do I create a post rotate to restart the xinetd service after the rotation?

Comment: use `systemctl`.

Comment: like `systemctl restart xinetd`?